# How to split a string by delimiter?

Tags: php, arrays, string, delimiter

I'm making a call to http://rolz.org/api/?4d20.json and the details element looks is a string in the format of `[ 12 +14 +2 +8 ]`.

I want to be able to segregate each value from this string to display on its own, in an array. At first I was using `str_split()` on the element, but I soon realized there is no standard length for value - a result could be 1, 2, 3 or longer in length. The only common delimiter is the plus-symbol.

How can I take a string value in the format stated and put it in a simple indexed array?

I figure this is a common menial task, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried `preg_split` and `str_split`. `preg_split` doesn't want to let me execute on plus-signs and / or brackets.

Comment: ...just use regex to extract the numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653159/php-extract-all-whole-numbers-into-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest following approach:

1. use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to filter `[`, `]` and "space" characters;
2. use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split string values by `+` character;
3. use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array-map) + [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to clean up each value.

---

```
$value = ' [ 12 +14 +2 +8 ] ';

$result = explode('+', trim($value, '[] '));

$result = array_map('trim', $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Shows:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "14"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```

Comment: I get:

`array (size=3)
  0 => string '[ 49' (length=4)
  1 => string '66' (length=2)
  2 => string '17  ]' (length=5)`
which includes the brackets

Comment: @JonMitten did you used `trim($value, '[]')` with *second argument*?

Comment: Yes, here is my function:
`function detailsToArray($stripDetails){
    $value = $stripDetails;
    $result = explode('+', trim($value, '[]'));
    $result = array_map('trim', $result);
    
    return $result;
}`

Comment: @JonMitten Is your php version > `4.1` ?

Comment: It looks like there are actually 2 spaces after the last value, before the closing bracket. Would that matter?

Comment: @JonMitten Yes. Add space to `trim()`s charlist, like `trim($value, '[] ')`.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $detail = " [ 14 +20 +14 +16 ] ";
    $arr = explode('+',str_replace(array(" ","[","]"),"",$detail));
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

shows

`Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 20 [2] => 14 [3] => 16 )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode`

```
$result = explode('+', $yourString);
```

Answer (score -1):

From SanKalp Mishra's answer, i just like to add something.

Use explode

```
$result = explode("+", $yourString);

$firstStr = $result[0];
$secondStr = $result[1];
$thirdStr = $result[2];
$fourthStr = $result[3];
```

and that is ready to be inserted in an array.