# PHP extract all whole numbers into an array

Tags: php

I have following string:

```
15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1
```

and all that i want is to extract all numbers from it into an array, so it will looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "15"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "26"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "354"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Is there a way in PHP to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string = '15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1';
preg_match_all('/\b(\d+)\b/', $string, $numbers);

var_dump($numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [Demo](https://eval.in/170887)

### Solution 1 :

This solution use [is_numeric function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) :

```
print_r(array_filter(split(" ", "15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1"),"is_numeric"));
```

### Solution 2 :

This solution use your own function :

```
function is_number($var) { return !(0 == intval($var)); }
print_r(array_filter(split(" ", "15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1"),"is_number"));
```

### Solution 3 :

To 5.3.0 and more, this solution use [preg_split function](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-split.php) :

```
print_r(array_filter(preg_split(" ", "15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1"),"is_numeric"));
```

Comment: The `split()` function is deprecated.

Comment: Thank Gergo Erdosi to see this.

Comment: Praveen Kumar: Me too, I have +2/-1

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '15 asdas 26 dasda 354 dasd 1';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

use preg_match: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

check examples at site bottom.